# If we have $x$ things, and $y$ of them are the same and $z$ of them are different, is the amount of combinations $x$ things $x! \over z!$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

If we have $x$ things, and $y$ of them are the same (these $y$ elements are all the same with respect to each of the other $y$ elements) and $z$ of them are different (such that they form a set of $z$ elements in which no 2 elements are repeated) where $x=y+z$, is the amount of combinations (without caring about order, using all of the $x$ elements)  $x! \over z!$? I believe this to be the case as there are $z!$ ways of ordering each permutation out of the $x!$ ones we have if we conceive of everything as being semantically different. However, I don't have a great intuition for combinatorics and am feeling unsure, hence my question.

Comment: If the things are A, A, A, A, B, B, C then how many are the same and how many are different?

Comment: To clarify I think you mean examples such as the following:  You have 7 hats of which 4 are blue and the other 3 are distinct non-blue colors (ignoring other possible differences between hats!).  If that is the case, would the scenario in the prior comment not be applicable?  So you would like to count permutations such as $AAAABCD$ which would be distinct from $ABDAACA$ where $A$ is a blue hat?

Comment: @AlgTop1854 sorry, I meant to ask about the amount of combinations here not of ways to order the entire thing. Yes, the example you gave of the set from which we choose is the type of set of which I am conceiving here.

Comment: It's $\frac{x!}{y!}$. You want to divide out by reordering the ones that are the same.

Comment: @Shmuel My comment was based on your post prior to your edits! Changes/refresh can out of sync with comments. But, I originally came up with $\frac{x!}{y!}$ and that still holds, as order still matters for the distinct objects $z_i$.  If it seems odd that $z$ is not in the result, it cancelled out in the calculation.